# Wanted to pass parameter in <img> src attribute URL in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, image, react-hooks

I wanted to pass `code` parameter in the URL of the src attribute of `<img>` in a react component. I have done the below implementation but it showing invalid src in console

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

const TimeZoneComponent = () => {

const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [city,setCity] = useState('');
const [printCity, setPrintCity] = useState(false);


const clickfn = () =>
{
    setPrintCity(true);
    if(printCity)
    {
        timeZone(city);
    }
}


async function timeZone(city) {
    await fetch(`http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/${city}`)
    .then((response)=>response.json())
    .then((json)=>{
        //console.log(json);
        setData(json);
    })
}



useEffect(()=> {
        timeZone();
},[])

let mystr = JSON.stringify(data.datetime);

console.log("city typed  =  "+city);

const cityToCodeMatcher = (city) => {
    let code;
    if(city === "Kolkata") code='IN';
    else if(city === "Tokyo") code='JP';
    return code;
}

const readySRC = (city) => {
    let temp =  "https://www.countryflags.io/".concat(cityToCodeMatcher(city));
    return temp.concat("/shiny/64.png");
}



return(
    <>
    <div className="timezone">       
        <div id="timezone-input">
            <label>Type Asian City Here..
                <br/>
            <input type="text" placeholder=" Type city here.." onChange={(event)=>setCity(event.target.value)}/>
                <br/>
            <Button className="timezone-button" onClick={()=>clickfn()} >Get Current DateTime</Button>
            </label>
        </div>
        Date: {mystr?.slice(1,11)} <br/>
        Time: {mystr?.slice(12,20)} <br/>
        Timezone: {data.timezone}
        <div>
            //Here I want to pass parameter in src of<img>
            <img src={readySRC({city})} alt="Country flag"/>
            ///////////
        </div>
    </div>
    </>
);

}
export default TimeZoneComponent;
```

Do anyone help how to do so?

Comment: If you're using fetch with a then, there's no reason to use async await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src={readySRC({city})} alt="Country flag"/>
```

readSRC({city}) means

```
readSRC({
   city: city
});
```

in your code should be

```
readSRC(city)
```

Comment: It works but I am getting delayed responses when I input city in the same code, do we have any way to speed up the API response of timeZone API.

Comment: @MohitMaroliyaB17CS036, Delayed response is just a network delay, your code has some other problem, img will always has wrong source.